# Powershell script is invoked twice

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me why the "Merge PDF's.bat file in the script below executes multiple times when a PDF is put in the 'D:\Folder' ? I only need it to execute once.

```
$folder = 'D:\Folder'
$filter = '*.PDF'   

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = 
$false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Start-Sleep -s 15
Invoke-Item 'C:\Merge PDF\Merge PDFs.bat'}
```

Comment: try `Write-Host` instead of `Invoke-Item` and see if it's written multiple times.

Comment: do you maybe still have an old event hooked from a previous execution?

Comment: my understanding is that EVERY ITEM in the ChangeType listing will trigger the Action. your code makes it seem you have two such filter triggers.

Comment: So what I noticed is, if there are two pdf's in the folder it runs the merge pdf twice. How can i stop that. I would like to run the merge pdf once. Doesn't matter how many pdf's are in the folder.